# How to return the value of an asynchronous callback?

Tags: java, asynchronous, callback

This is my code, it's a query to mysql for return 1 or 0, if exist a element in database. I want to know how I get the value?

```
private void comprobarUsuario(String url){

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    String ob = "IF(EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `loginusuario` WHERE `idusuario`='" + id.getText() + "' and `contrasena`='" + contra.getText() + "'), '1', '0')";
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    jsonObject.getString(ob) //I want return this value *-*-*-* 

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error de conexion",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Comment: Hey Javier, are you trying to get the value from DB? Which mean you need help with query or you asking to get data from ‘obj’ object that was returned by query.

Comment: no, I don't know how to return the value from where I call the method comprobarusuario

Comment: JsonArrayRequest, Response.Listener - belong to which library?

Comment: com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

Comment: I want return the object jsonObject.getString(ob), it is inside of the try-catch